# Understanding unicode codecvt

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a UTF-16 encoded stream and I'd like to convert it into plain ASCII, i.e. if there's an ASCII character -> print it. If a codeunit represents something else I don't care e.g. chinese characters) -> output garbage.

I'm using this code

```
typedef std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t> convert_typeX;
std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;
std::string converted = converterX.from_bytes(str);
```

and it seems to work.. but why?

[documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16) for `codecvt_utf16` states:

> std::codecvt_utf16 is a std::codecvt facet which encapsulates conversion between a UTF-16 encoded byte string and UCS2 or UCS4 character string (depending on the type of Elem).

UCS2 is a version of unicode as far as I know.. so this code is converting to a sequence of `wchar_t` bytes that represent unicode characters right? How come I'm getting ASCII bytes?

Comment: @Simple since wikipedia sucks at explaining this, could you expand on that?

Comment: UCS-2 is obsolete terminology which refers to a Unicode implementation up to Unicode 1.1, before surrogate code points and UTF-16 were added to Version 2.0 of the standard. This term should now be avoided. UCS-2 does not describe a data format distinct from UTF-16, because both use exactly the same 16-bit code unit representations. However, UCS-2 does not interpret surrogate code points, and thus cannot be used to conformantly represent supplementary characters... (http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-11)

Comment: I would think this code should not compile as-is, because `converterX.from_bytes()` returns a `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`, which you are assigning to a `std::string` instead of a `std:::wstring`.

Comment: it does with unicode properties selected in the project pane (MSVC). Probably because that means `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about unicode is that unicode values 0-127 represent ASCII characters 0-127.

So, you don't even need to waste your time with `std::codecvt`. All you have to do is scan your UTF-16 sequence, grab all UTF-16 values in the range of 0-127 (see the wikipedia entry for UTF-16 for the simple process of extracting UTF-16 values from the bytestream), and you'll end up with plain ASCII, as if by magic. That's because, by definition, values above 127 are not plain ASCII. You can do whatever you want with all other characters.

And, if you would like to expand your universe to `iso-8859-1`, rather than `US-ASCII`, you can expand your range to 0-255. Because unicode values 128-255 are also equivalent to characters 128-255 in the `iso-8859-1` codeset.

Comment: What you're suggesting is nontrivial behavior (even if it's simpler than a UTF8 conversion) that probably should be encapsulated in a custom `codecvt` facet.